# Open magnific popup

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I need help to open the popup by using magnific popup.

https://codepen.io/victoreugen2002/pen/poeoKPg

```
   $('#open-popup').on('click', function (e) {
    jQuery('#open-popup').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        midClick: true, // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.
 
    }).magnificPopup('open');

    e.preventDefault();
```

The html content:

```
<a href="#open-popup" class="small-button">
    <div class="button-text">Open Modal ></div>
</a>
<div id="open-popup" class="mfp-hide white-popup">
    <h3>I'm a Modal</h3>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent malesuada venenatis cursus. Donec suscipit enim id nulla vestibulum interdum. Morbi tempus venenatis neque pulvinar volutpat. Ut bibendum urna eu molestie euismod. Nullam sit amet turpis tristique, maximus lectus at, venenatis ante.
    
        Phasellus faucibus euismod velit eget porta. Nullam maximus libero dolor, quis ornare nulla pharetra euismod. Fusce pretium sagittis augue, vitae faucibus odio accumsan at. Quisque maximus semper volutpat. Cras vel velit sodales, lacinia sapien ut, vulputate orci. Ut diam elit, mollis ac ultrices sit amet, ultricies et nisl.
       
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First what I would do is add `open-popup-link` to your `<a>`,

then remove the `.magnificPopup('open')`, so your code looks like.

```
$('a[href="#open-popup"]').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#open-popup').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',
    midClick: true // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.
  })
});
```

Also note, that you have to change `$('#open-popup').on('click'` to `$('a[href="#open-popup"]').on('click'`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  initPopups();
});

function initPopups() {

  $('a[href="#open-popup"]').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#open-popup').magnificPopup({
      type: 'inline',
      midClick: true // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.
    })
  });


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="#open-popup" class="open-popup-link small-button">
  <div class="button-text">Open Modal ></div>
</a>
<div id="open-popup" class="mfp-hide white-popup">
  <h3>I'm a Modal</h3>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent malesuada venenatis cursus. Donec suscipit enim id nulla vestibulum interdum. Morbi tempus venenatis neque pulvinar volutpat. Ut bibendum urna eu molestie euismod. Nullam sit amet turpis
  tristique, maximus lectus at, venenatis ante. Phasellus faucibus euismod velit eget porta. Nullam maximus libero dolor, quis ornare nulla pharetra euismod. Fusce pretium sagittis augue, vitae faucibus odio accumsan at. Quisque maximus semper volutpat.
  Cras vel velit sodales, lacinia sapien ut, vulputate orci. Ut diam elit, mollis ac ultrices sit amet, ultricies et nisl.

</div>
```